How to evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2} \ln ^2\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right) d x$

Question

How to evaluate
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2} \ln ^2\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right) d x$$

Attempt

\begin{aligned}
& I=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2} \ln ^2\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right) d x \\
& \stackrel{x \rightarrow \frac{1}{1+x}}{=} \int_{\infty}^0 \frac{\frac{1}{1+x}}{1+\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}} \ln ^2\left(\frac{\frac{1}{1+x}}{\frac{x}{1+x}}\right) \frac{-1}{(1+x)^2} d x=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^2(x)}{(1+x)\left(1+(1+x)^2\right)} d x \\
& \text { *Now : } \\
& I=\int_0^1 \frac{x(\ln (x)-\ln (1-x))^2}{1+x^2} d x \\
& =\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{x \ln ^2(x)}{1+x^2} d x}_A-2 \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{x \ln (x) \ln (1-x)}{1+x^2} d x}_B+\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{x \ln ^2(1-x)}{1+x^2} d x}_C \\
& A=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \int_0^1 x^{2 n+1} \ln ^2(x) d x=\frac{1}{4} \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^3}}_{\eta(3)}=\frac{1}{4} \frac{3 \zeta(3)}{4}=\frac{3 \zeta(3)}{16} \\
\end{aligned}
I don't know how to evaluate integrals $B$ and $C$. New methods to evaluate $I$ are welcome. Also, is it possible to evaluate
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2} \ln^n \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right) \, dx
$$
for general $n$?

Why downvotes???

For a complex number $z\ne -1$, the following identity holds:
$$\int_0^1\frac{z\ln^{q}(\frac{x}{1-x})}{1+zx}dx=2(-1)^{q}q!\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor\frac{q}{2}\rfloor}\frac{\ln^{q-2n+1}(1+z)}{(q-2n+1)!}\eta(2n).\tag{1}$$
Proof: Let $z=t-1$ and then make the change of variable $\frac{x}{1-x}=y$, we get
$$\int_0^1\frac{z\ln^{q}(\frac{x}{1-x})}{1+zx}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{(1-t)\ln^{q}(y)}{(1+ty)(1+y)}dy$$
$$=(-1)^{q}\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{\partial^{q}}{\partial s^{q}}\int_0^\infty\frac{(1-t)y^{-s}}{(1+ty)(1+y)}dy$$
$$=(-1)^{q}\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{\partial^{q}}{\partial s^{q}}\bigg(\int_0^\infty\frac{y^{-s}}{1+y}dy-\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac{ty^{-s}}{1+ty}dy}_{ty\to y}\bigg)$$
$$=(-1)^{q}\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{\partial^{q}}{\partial s^{q}}(1-t^s)\int_0^\infty\frac{y^{-s}}{1+y}dy$$
$$=(-1)^{q}\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{\partial^{q}}{\partial s^{q}}(1-t^s)\pi\csc(\pi s)$$
expand both functions in Taylor series
$$=(-1)^{q}\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{\partial^{q}}{\partial s^{q}}\left(-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\ln^{n+1}(t)}{(n+1)!}s^{n+1}\right)\left(2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\eta(2n) s^{2n-1}\right)$$
use the Cauchy product $\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n} x^n\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^\infty {b}_{2n} x^{2n}\bigg)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor} a_{n-2k}b_{2k}\bigg)x^n$
$$=2(-1)^{q-1}\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{\partial^{q}}{\partial s^{q}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor} \frac{\ln^{n-2k+1}(t)}{(n-2k+1)!}\eta(2k)}_{f(n)}\bigg)s^n.$$
The proof completes on employing $\lim_{s\to0}\frac{\partial^{q}}{\partial s^{q}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)s^{n}=q!f(q)$.
Substitute $z=a+bi$ in $(1)$ and then consider the real and imaginary parts, we obtain:
$$\int_0^1\frac{((a^2+b^2)x+a))\ln^{q}(\frac{x}{1-x})}{(a^2+b^2)x^2+2ax+1}dx=2(-1)^{q}q!\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor\frac{q}{2}\rfloor}\frac{\Re\ln^{q-2n+1}(1+a+bi)}{(q-2n+1)!}\eta(2n)\tag{2}$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{b\ln^{q}(\frac{x}{1-x})}{(a^2+b^2)x^2+2ax+1}dx=2(-1)^{q}q!\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor\frac{q}{2}\rfloor}\frac{\Im\ln^{q-2n+1}(1+a+bi)}{(q-2n+1)!}\eta(2n).\tag{3}$$
To get your integral, let $(a,b)=(0,1)$ in $(2)$ and note that
$$\Re\ln^{r}(1+i)=2^{-r}\sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor\frac{r}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^p\binom{r}{2p}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2p}\ln^{r-2p}(2).$$

You made it look so simple.

(+1) Excellent work.

You can check that your integral can be expressed as
$$\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm da^2}\right|_{a=1}\int_0^1\dfrac{x^a}{(1+x^2)(1-x)^{a-1}}\,\mathrm d x$$
and according to WA
$$\int_0^1\dfrac{x^a}{(1+x^2)(1-x)^{a-1}}\,\mathrm d x=\pi\left(2^{\frac{1-a}{2}}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}(1+a)\right)-1 \right)\csc(\pi a)$$
Furthermore, in the general case,
$$\int_0^1\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}\ln^n\left(\dfrac{x}{1-x}\right)\,\mathrm dx=\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm da^n}\right|_{a=1}\int_0^1\dfrac{x^a}{(1+x^2)(1-x)^{a-1}}\,\mathrm d x$$
In this later case I suggest expanding the previous result around $a=1$ and finding the $n$th coefficient multiplied by $n!$.
Some values are
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_0^1\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}\ln\left(\dfrac{x}{1-x}\right)\,\mathrm dx=\dfrac{\pi^2-4\log^2(2)}{32}\\
&\int_0^1\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}\ln^2\left(\dfrac{x}{1-x}\right)\,\mathrm dx=\dfrac{4\log^3(2)+13\pi^2\log(2)}{96}\\
&\int_0^1\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}\ln^3\left(\dfrac{x}{1-x}\right)\,\mathrm dx=\dfrac{31\pi^4 -16\log^4(2)-104\pi^2\log^2(2)}{1024}
\end{aligned}
$$

Thanks alot,very nice answer

For the first problem
$$I=\int \frac{x}{1+x^2} \log ^2\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\,dx$$
$$\frac{x}{1-x}=t \implies x=\frac{t}{t+1}\implies dx=\frac{dt}{(t+1)^2}$$
$$I=\int\frac{t }{2 t^3+4 t^2+3 t+1}\log ^2(t)\,dt$$
Write
$$A=\frac{t }{2 t^3+4 t^2+3 t+1}=\frac{t }{2(t+1)(t-a)(t-b)}$$ where
$$a=-\frac{1+i}{2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad b=-\frac{1-i}{2}$$
Using partial fraction decomposition
$$A=-\frac{1}{2 (a+1) (b+1) (t+1)}+\frac 1{2(a-b)}\Bigg(\frac{a}{(a+1) (t-a)} -\frac{b}{(b+1) (t-b)} \Bigg)$$
So, we face three integrals
$$J_c=\int \frac{\log ^2(t)}{t+c}\,dt$$
Two integrations by parts lead to
$$J_c=\log ^2(t)\, \log \left(1+\frac{t}{c}\right)+2 \,\log (t)\, \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{t}{c}\right)-2\, \text{Li}_3\left(-\frac{t}{c}\right)$$
Recombing the antiderivatives and then using the bounds $(0,\infty)$, the raw result is
$$\frac{1}{6} \left(\log ^3(1-i)+\log ^3(1+i)+\pi ^2
   (\log (1-i)+\log (1+i))\right)$$ Simplifying the complex numbers
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2} \ln ^2\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\,dx=\frac{1}{96} \log (2) \left(13 \pi ^2+4 \log
   ^2(2)\right)$$
For the extension
$$I_n=\int \frac{x}{1+x^2} \log ^n\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\,dx$$ you can keep the same approach which will require more integration by parts
$$\int \frac{\log ^3(t)}{t+c}\,dt=\log ^3(t) \log \left(1+\frac{t}{c}\right)+3 \log ^2(t) \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{t}{c}\right)-$$ $$6 \log (t) \text{Li}_3\left(-\frac{t}{c}\right)+6 \text{Li}_4\left(-\frac{t}{c}\right)$$

Answer using complex analysis
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{x}{x^2+1}\ln^2\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2x}{(x+1)(x^2+2x+2)}dx$$
Define $f(z)=\frac{\ln^3z}{(z+1)(z^2+2z+2)}$ and integrate $f(z)$ on a traditional keyhole contour with a branch cut on the positive real axis and $0≤arg(z)≤2\pi$.
$$\oint_Cf(z)dz=\left(\int_\Gamma+\int_\gamma+\int_{\psi_1}+\int_{\psi_2}\right)f(z)dz$$
Evaluate $\oint_C f(z)dz$
$$\operatorname{Res}_{z=-1}f(z)=\frac{\ln^3z}{z^2+2z+2}\Bigg|_{z=-1}=(\pi i)^3=-\pi^3i$$
$$\operatorname{Res}_{z=-1+i}f(z)=\frac{\ln^3z}{(z+1)(z+1+i)}\Bigg|_{z=-1+i}=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\ln2}{2}+\frac{3\pi i}{4}\right)^3$$
$$\operatorname{Res}_{z=-1-i}f(z)=\frac{\ln^3z}{(z+1)(z+1-i)}\Bigg|_{z=-1-i}=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\ln2}{2}+\frac{5\pi i}{4}\right)^3$$
$$\oint_C f(z)dz=2\pi i\sum\operatorname{Res}=\left(-\frac{3\pi^4}{8}+\frac{3\pi^2}{2}\ln^22\right)+i\left(\frac{51\pi^3}{16}\ln2-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln^32\right)$$
Both $\int_\gamma$ and $\int_\Gamma$ go to $0$ as $R→\int$ and $\epsilon→0$. Evaluate $\int_{\psi_1}+\int_{\psi_2}$
$$\lim_{R→\infty,\epsilon→0}\int_{\psi_1 U \psi_2}f(z)dz=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3z}{(z+1)(z^2+2z+2)}dz+\int_\infty^0\frac{(\ln z+2\pi i)^3}{(z+1)(z^2+2z+2)}dz$$
$$=12\pi^2\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln z}{(z+1)(z^2+2z+2)}dz+i\left(-6\pi I+8\pi^3\int_0^\infty\frac{dz}{(z+1)(z^2+2z+2)}\right)$$$$=12\pi^2J+i(-6\pi I+4\pi^3\ln 2)$$
Plugging everything in we get, take the real and imaginary parts and solve
$$12\pi^2J+i(-6\pi I+4\pi^3\ln 2)=\left(-\frac{3\pi^4}{8}+\frac{3\pi^2}{2}\ln^22\right)+i\left(\frac{51\pi^3}{16}\ln2-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln^32\right)$$
$$J=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln z}{(z+1)(z^2+2z+2}dz=-\frac{\pi^2}{32}+\frac{\ln^22}{8} $$
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{x}{x^2+1}\ln^2\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2x}{(x+1)(x^2+2x+2)}dx=\left(\frac{13\pi^2}{96}+\frac{\ln^22}{24}\right)\ln2$$

Incomplete solution.
Let $n\geq 2$, an integer.
\begin{align}J_n&=\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln^n\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)}{1+x^2}dx\\
&\overset{u=\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^n\left(\frac{1-y}{2y}\right)}{1+y}dy+(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^1 \frac{y\ln^n\left(\frac{2y}{1-y}\right)}{1+y^2}dy\\
&=\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^n\left(\frac{1-y}{2y}\right)}{1+y}dy}_{=A_n}+(-1)^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}J_{k}\ln^{n-k}2\\
A_n&\overset{u=\frac{2y}{1-y}}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^nu}{(1+u)(1+2u)}du\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{((-1)^n-1)\ln^nu}{1+u}du+2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^nu}{1+2u}du}_{=B_n}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^nu}{1+\frac{u}{2}}du\\
&=\frac{(1-(-1)^n)(2^n-1)n!\zeta(n+1)}{2^n}+2B_n+n!\text{Li}_{n+1}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
B_n&=\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^nu}{1+2u}du}_{z=2u}+\underbrace{\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^nu}{1+2u}du}_{z=\frac2u}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^n\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)}{1+z}dz+(-1)^n\int_1^2\frac{\ln^nz}{z(z+2)}dz\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}\ln^{n-k}2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^kz}{1+z}dz+\frac{(-1)^n\ln^{n+1}2}{2(n+1)}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4}\underbrace{\int_1^2\frac{\ln^nz}{1+\frac{z}{2}}dz}_{C_n}\\
&=(-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}k!(2^k-1)\zeta(k+1)\ln^{n-k}2}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{(-1)^n(n+2)\ln^{n+1}2}{2(n+1)}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}C_n}{4}\\
C_n&\overset{w=\frac z2}=2\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^n\left(2w\right)}{1+w}dw=2\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\ln^{n-k}2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^kw}{1+w}dw-2\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^n(2w)}{1+w}dw}_{y=2w}\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\ln^{n-k}2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^kw}{1+w}dw-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^ny}{1+\frac y2}dy\\
&=2\ln^{n+1}2+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}k!(2^k-1)\zeta(k+1)\ln^{n-k}2}{2^{k-1}}+2(-1)^nn!\text{Li}_{n+1}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
B_n&=\frac{(-1)^n}{2(n+1)}\ln^{n+1}2+(-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(1-(-1)^k)\binom{n}{k}k!(2^k-1)\zeta(k+1)\ln^{n-k}2}{2^{k+1}}-\\
&\frac{n!}{2}\text{Li}_{n+1}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
A_n&=\frac{(-1)^n\ln^{n+1}2}{n+1}+(-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(1-(-1)^k)\binom{n}{k}k!(2^k-1)\zeta(k+1)\ln^{n-k}2}{2^{k}}\\
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}\boxed{J_n=\\\frac{(-1)^n\ln^{n+1}2}{n+1}+(-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(1-(-1)^k)\binom{n}{k}k!(2^k-1)\zeta(k+1)\ln^{n-k}2}{2^{k}}+(-1)^{n+1}\times\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}J_{k}\ln^{n-k}2}\\
\end{align}
If $n$ is even then,
\begin{align}
\boxed{J_n=\\\frac{\ln^{n+1}2}{2(n+1)}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(1-(-1)^k)\binom{n}{k}k!(2^k-1)\zeta(k+1)\ln^{n-k}2}{2^{k+1}}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k}J_{k}\ln^{n-k}2}\\
\end{align}

TBH,Very nice answer(+1)
