An Interesting Integral of Weight 4 (from Pisco)
An interesting integral is given in this post by Pisco, that is
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2}(\log x)(\log(1+x))^2 dx $$
$$= -\frac{15 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{8}-\frac{7}{4} \zeta (3) \log  2+\frac{467 \pi ^4}{23040}-\frac{5}{64} \log ^4 2+\frac{3}{32}\pi ^2 \log ^22.$$
Why interesting? For example, from the perspective of attacking elegantly the problem, without getting into complicated calculations - it seems a hard nut to crack at first sight, and not easy to get to manageable integrals and series.
Here is a route proposed by Cornel, in large steps:
$1)$ We start with using the identity, $\displaystyle \log^3\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)=\log^3(x)-3  \log ^2(x)\log (1+x)+3  \log (x)\log ^2(1+x)-\log ^3(1+x).$
$2)$ The integral
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2}\log^3\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right) \textrm{d}x$$
is manageable upon considering the variable change $\displaystyle \frac{x}{1+x}\mapsto x$.
$3)$ Further, for the next key integral, we notice the key step,
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2}\log^2(x)\log(1+x)\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2}\log^2(x)\log(1-x^2)\textrm{d}x}_{\displaystyle x^2 \mapsto x}-\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2}\log^2(x)\log(1-x)\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)}{1+x}\textrm{d}x-\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2}\log^2(x)\log(1-x)\textrm{d}x$$
$$\small =\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \int_0^1 x^{n-1}\log^2(x)\log(1-x)\textrm{d}x-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\int_0^1 x^{2n-1}\log^2(x)\log(1-x)\textrm{d}x,$$
and from here we can perform a transformation to manageable and known harmonic series, which are all given in (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019) and its sequel, More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series: A New Collection of Fiendish Problems and Surprising Solutions (2023). Of course, it is useful to employ the integral result,
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}\log^2(x)\log(1-x)\textrm{d}x=2\zeta(3)\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\pi^2}{3}\frac{1}{n^2}-2\frac{H_n}{n^3}-2\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}-2\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n},$$
which may also be found in the sequel, page $33$. In fact, for the first integral after the last equal sign we can also exploit
$$\int_0^1\frac{\displaystyle \log^m(x)\log\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1-x}\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(-1)^{m-1} m!\biggr((m+1)\zeta (m+2)-\sum_{k=0}^m \eta (k+1)\eta (m-k+1)\biggr),$$
combined with integration by parts. This last generlization may be found in the sequel, page $38$. Another approach involves directly transforming the integral to skew-harmonic series.
$4)$ Finally, the integral
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x \log^3(1+x)}{1+x^2}\textrm{d}x,$$
we already have it in a generalized form in More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series: A New Collection of Fiendish Problems and Surprising Solutions (2023), pages $11$-$12$,
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x\log^n(1+x)}{a^2+x^2}\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\log^{n-k}(2)\Re\biggr\{\operatorname{Li}_{k+1}\left(\frac{2}{1-ia}\right)\biggr\}+(-1)^n  n! \Re\biggr\{\operatorname{Li}_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{1-ia}\right)\biggr\}$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\log^{n-k}(2)\Re\biggr\{\operatorname{Li}_{k+1}\left(1+e^{i 2\theta}\right)\biggr\}+(-1)^n  n! \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(k\theta) \cos^k(\theta)}{k^{n+1}},$$
where $n$ is a natural number and $\displaystyle a=\tan(\theta), \theta \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.
A paper with a full solution will be ready soon.
Question: What other strategies would you consider for evaluating the integral?
Greetings to Pisco! :-)

Maybe helpful, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4966287/1298448 (+1)

@Martin.s Thanks. I'll check later.

Using $x=\frac{1}{t}-1$ leads to
$$\int _0^1\frac{x\ln \left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(1+x\right)}{1+x^2}:dx=\int _{\frac{1}{2}}^1\left(\frac{1}{t}+\Re \left{\frac{1+i}{1-\left(1+i\right)t}\right}\right)\left(\ln ^2\left(t\right)\ln \left(1-t\right)-\ln ^3\left(t\right)\right):dt.$$
Tedious but manageable integrals are involved which contain
$$\Re \left{\text{Li}_4\left(1+i\right)\right},:\Re \left{\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\right}.$$

@JorgeLayja Interesting approach. Thanks.
